# Submenu or dropdown inside dropdown in Materialize 1.0

Tags: materialize

Up to version 1.0, it was straightforward to add a dropdown inside another dropdown. It was just adding the < a> trigger < /a> inside the  < li> tag < /li>.

Now, is that right we cannot have submenu or sub-dropdown in version 1.0?

I have tried for hours if not days at this point.

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle or code sample of what you have tried?

Comment: I came up with two solutions: 1 was a hardcoded submenu inside 2) an materializecss collapsible accordion (my menu is horizontal).

Comment: This was so simple with version < 1.0....